# IIS cannot access folder for website hosting

Tags: windows-7, iis, iis-7

I've installed IIS on my Windows 7 to test ASP.NET websites, however it seems that it cannot host it since it has no access to the folder I am assigning it to. I've tried different folders but no luck, searched google for some help but cannot find anything.

Anyway, this is error message:

> The server is configured to use pass-through authentication with a
>   built-in account to access the specified physical path. However, IIS
>   Manager cannot verify whether the built-in account has access. Make
>   sure that the application pool identity has Read access to the
>   physical path. If this server is joined to a domain, and the
>   application pool identity is NetworkService or LocalSystem, verify
>   that \$ has Read access to the physical path.
>   Then test these settings again.

Here is screenshot, just in case:
[image]

Comment: Check this: http://www.somacon.com/p581.php

Answer (score 1):

Check this out... it should help resolve your issue.

http://msmvps.com/blogs/bernard/archive/2009/11/04/warning-authorization-cannot-verify-access-to-path-c-inetpub-wwwroot.aspx

Comment: tl;dr; - it's just a warning because it's not testing under the actual IIS user - try accessing the site and it should work.